# Is Ippu a Japanese word or cultural reference?

Tags: translation, words

I was considering this word 'ippu' 2 syllables in English as a brand name - no meaning as far as I know but there were vague references online to Japan. Anyone heard that word before?

Answer (score 3):

*Ippu* can indeed seem like a [Romanized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese) Japanese word (i.e., a Japanese word written in Latin alphabet).

- **一風** (*ippu*, literally "one wind" or "one style"):

  - An adverb that means "in a way", "somehow (different)", etc. (Usually used with 変わった)
  - Used in some Japanese proper names. For example it is used as part of [一風堂](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ippudo), a ramen restaurant chain. 堂 (*do*) is a suffix for stores.
- **一封** (*ippu*, literally "one seal", "one envelope"):

  - Used to refer to money or a document sealed in an envelope.

一風 is actively used as a brand name (or as part of a brand name) in Japan. As a native Japanese speaker, if I saw 'ippu' on the street outside Japan, I would suspect it is perhaps related to Japan. (But I also know a coincidence like this happens often.)

Comment: I could go for some 一風堂 right now.  So hungry...

Comment: Ok thank you that's very helpful 

Comment: Could it not also be 一歩, one pawn in shogi?

Comment: @Jan I think "one pawn in shogi" is normally counted as 歩{ふ} + 一枚{いちまい}. [一歩{いっぷ}千金{せんきん}](https://yoji-jukugo.com/%E4%B8%80%E6%AD%A9%E5%8D%83%E9%87%91/) is a well-known aphorism at shogi game.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Ah, so いっぷ would *only* apply to that aphorism?

Comment: @Jan I think 一歩 is normally read as いっぽ e.g “first step”. Shogi player uses the aphorism, but non shogi player normally read 一歩 as いっぽ.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thank you very much!